# How exactly does the selected value of a selectList work?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, selectlist

I need to create a dropdown list and I'm doing this by creating a new SelectList based on a model. Here is how I am trying to do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedStudio, new SelectList(Model.Studios, "Id", "Name", Model.Studio)
```

I see from the class signature that the last parameter is object selectedValue. I have now tried many variations, trying to pass a string there, an object, etc. but when I compile the program, the selected value for the dropdown list is never set to what I want.

Can anyone explain how this works?

EDIT: I don't know if this is important, but the Id of Studio is of type ObjectId (from the MongoDB C# Driver)

Answer (score 0):

I think your not setting for the selected value on new SelectList

your code should be

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedStudio, new SelectList(Model.Studios, "Id", "Name", [Defualt value])
```

the reason it not give the error becuase it  is object. and your setting up your IEnumerable list. so it is object. see the following link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok Let me know which part that you can't understand. Let me know Model.Studios is your Ienurable list?

Comment: yes, model.studios is my ienumerable list which loads in the dropdown list. However, specifying the selectedValue (the last parameter) does nothing. So I'm assuming then, that the last parameter might not do what I assumed it does, so in that case, what does the last parameter do? Or am I passing the last param incorrectly.

Comment: What is your property name that selected value taking from list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedStudio, new SelectList(Model.Studios, "Id", "Name", Model.Studio.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how u keep a value selected in drop down

```
        @Html.DropDownList("statussearch", new List<SelectListItem>
                                    {
                                        new SelectListItem { Text = "text1", Value = "1",  Selected = Studio.IsSelected.HasValue ? Studio.IsSelected.Value : false},
                                        new SelectListItem { Text = "text2", Value = "2"},
                                        new SelectListItem { Text = "text3", Value = "3"},
                                    }, "Select Status")
```

IsSelected is a field in your DB wch states wch value to be selected.

Comment: So basically, this isn't something I can populatr dynamically (with a model), and still choose a selected value? So in that case, what is the last param of the new selectlist supposed to do?

Comment: i use the database field because, no developer will like to update the code again again for only selected values
the last parameter of new selectlist is for htmlattribute's

Comment: for dynamic model values to be set as selectd u jus can replace the select status string with ur model value u wan to be selected
EG  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().name1).ToString()


this works for dynamic values which can be added in model

Comment: Well basically what I want to happen is: this is an edit view so it populates the select list with existing studios, and when the view loads, I would like the selected studio to be selected in the dropdown list and I thought this would be possible through selectlist's last param

Comment: studios is a property of ur model?  thn this is it, use html.displaynamefor(specify ur model property cast it to string )

Comment: Studios is the model so I tried @html.displaynamefor(model=>model.Studios.First().Name).ToString() however this just turned it into a label, I need Studios to be a dropdown list, and have a certain Studio from the Studios model selected by default when the view loads

Comment: @foreach (var value in studios){
@Html.DropDownList("statussearch", new List<SelectListItem>
{new SelectListItem { Text =value.prop1, Value = "1" },new SelectListItem { Text = value.prop2, Value = "2"},new SelectListItem { Text = value.prop3, Value = "3"},}, value.proptobeselected)}

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine for your requirement

```
    @foreach (var value in studios)
    { @Html.DropDownList("statussearch", new List<SelectListItem> 
    {new SelectListItem {    Text =value.prop1, Value = "1" },new SelectListItem { Text = value.prop2, Value = "2"},new SelectListItem { Text = value.prop3, Value = "3"},}, value.proptobeselected)}
```

Comment: this just creates a separate dropdownlist for each item I have in studios. I guess my only solution is to create a selectlist before the dropdown and then use it in the dropdownlist helper. I just thought that it would be easier to point to the value I want to be selected in the helper itself, however I'm having trouble with that.